# I want to see the dlls that are hooked to any process using python. Is it possible by pdb?

Tags: python, windows, pdb, pydbg

I want to see the dlls that are hooked to any process using python. Is it possible by pdb?

Is there any way to attach to a process or open a process from python debugger and view the dlls hooked?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do it with pdb. You can use pydbg instead. This a sample code which does that

```
import pydbg
from pydbg.defines import *
dbg = pydbg.pydbg()
dbg.attach(pid)
for modules in dbg.enumerate_modules():
   print modules
dbg.run()
```